# Жаргон и русское слово

Tags: значение-слов

Жаргон, сленг, арго - иностранные слова в русском языке. Не поверю, чтобы русский народ не знал, не понимал и не называл обобщённым русским словом те языковые ответвления, которые сейчас заняты иностранными словами "жаргон", "сленг", "арго". Вероятно, что перечисленные слова заместили собой русское слово. Вот бы найти это русское слово. Есть соображения?

Дополню. Я считаю, что это, искомое русское слово точнее и шире выражает указанные ответвления. 
Смотрите: "слово о полкУ ИгоревЕ", "слово о полкЕ ИгоревА" или: "тропою троянЮ". Литературный прием того времени и походит на жаргон. 
Думаю, что искомое слово где-то на виду, но используется не так, как ранее; сейчас его значение исковеркано и употребляется слово не так, как прежде.

Comment: А как вы отличаете русское слово от старославянского? Не могли бы Вы, пожалуйста, привести пример "русского слова"

Comment: душа, нос, сознание, небо, рука...

Comment: да даже: волхв, сварог, невеглас - русские слова... Я понял куда вы клоните. Осторожнее, не путайте письменность с речью.

Comment: Вы ищете название отдельным словам (жаргонизмам) или системе изъяснения в целом (жаргону)?

Comment: Ищу русское обобщённое слово, которое вбирает в себя все значения иностранных слов "жаргон", "сленг", "арго" (а также "феня", "падонковский", "олбанский") и которое говорит о других чертах, свойственным таким отклонениям.

Answer (score 1):

[Брокгауз и Ефрон](https://ru.wikisource.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%A1%D0%91%D0%95/%D0%96%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BD) предлагают "говор".

Comment: Одного слова маловато будет. Да и говор — шире, чем жаргон.

Comment: Хм, говор, наречие. Спасибо, поразмышляю!

Comment: Можно и русскую "феню" рассмотреть, "по" которой "ботают" :)

Comment: @Alex_ander, не стал писать в вопросе эту "феню", а так же: "олбанский" и "падонковский" - хватает слова "жаргон".

Comment: "Феня" (классический воровской жаргон) не имеет отношения к интернетовским падонкафф и пр. Это частный случай жаргона, имеющий русское внутреннее наименование.

Comment: Феня - это воровской жаргон, т.е. более узкое понятие. Олбанский - один из видов интернет-жаргона, т.е. тоже никак не обобщение. Говор шире, возможно, но в вопросе ведь это и нужно?

Answer (score 0):

Лучший вариант русского слова, которое я могу предложить на эту роль — **иноязычный**. Рискну предположить, что до того, как слово **жаргон** попало к нам из французского, потребность дифференцировать незнакомые слова на *жаргонизмы, диалектные, иностранные* и т.п. была не настолько выраженной и массовой, чтобы русские слова для этих понятий могли появиться и закрепиться в языке.

**Дополнение** (ответ на комментарий).
Поясню ещё раз подробнее. Если слово не воспринималось как "родное", оно могло считаться иноязычным. А если воспринималось как "родное", то никакого жаргона в нём никто не видел. Уже тогда существовали омонимы, значения которых определялись из контекста.

А, кстати, слово для понятия "омоним" вполне могло бы появиться в русском языке, мне кажется.

Comment: Пример: "не туда копаете". "Копаете" - жаргон и не иностранное, а русское слово. Считаете, что раньше под "иностранным" словом имели в виду жаргон? Интересная мысль! Но тут видно, что надо копать в сторону "красного словца".

Comment: Я дополнил ответ более подробными разъяснениями. Не придумывайте, пожалуйста, за меня, что я считаю.

Comment: Русский язык настолько крут (жаргон), что называл все точно до черточки.